# How to better save the rich string content with images in database?

Tags: java, mysql, database, string, image

I get a question when I save **the rich string content with images** into database, to do this I had some solutions at hand:

- Place string content's images on hard disk first, and save the string content which includes these images' paths, and for displaying the rich string content later on page there are 2 ways:

  - If the image is included in string content with **absolute path**, we directly display it on page, but this way may suffer from the problem of domain URL change, that means if our system deployed on another machine or URL, these images cannot be correctly displayed any more
  - If the image is included in string content with **relative path**, to make sure string content can be displayed on all path pages we need to dynamically add domain path in front of the image path, this causes low performance and is complex
- Using a new type of column that supports storing both string and image stream, but I'm not sure this is realistic

I'm using Java language for programming and MySQL as database. So What's the best way for me to do this? I know this is common case in Web development.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge currently there is no direct way in RDBMS for method two. There is no data type to store both Alphanumeric and Bytes.

You only have method one. And as you pointed out both has pros and cons. But instead of doing the two approaches suggested (Absolute path vs relative path) I would suggest the following.

1. Save all your images in Database in a separate Table. (This allows you to control the size of the images being uploaded and when migrating to different systems only database migration is required no file system migration is necessary). Table can have columns id, filename, extension, mime_type, length etc.
2. Have a Service method to save your Image file in the Database table and return the id of the image which will be unique.
3. Create a separate GET method for Image Retrieval ex:- `http://localhost/image/{id}` which will return the image for the step two returned id.

When you get the rich content with images save the images using the step two created service method and then get the id, append it with the Image retrieval url created in step 3 and place it in your rich content and then save it as a text value.

Ex:-

```
Abc def <img src="/image/{id}">
```

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Tks @shazin!! This sounds a good idea. As you taught, like implementation of verification code, image retrieval methods need write this image stream into response, right? This solution may cause performance issue since every time image retrieval, it will be read in memory and written in response, instead if we directly access image with URL by Web Server's static access way, it will be fairy efficient, right? But anyway, if there is the best solution I'd like to take your advice. Thanks so much.